# Unable to Install Rails and other Ruby Gems on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have properly setup homebrew and Ruby Version 2.3.1 following this site https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan. However, when I tried to install Rails or other ruby gems I have gotten this error -

```
sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I've tried searching for the answer here on the forum but couldn't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try not `sudo`.

Comment: this is outside of scope. You should post this on Super User

Comment: i've tried without `sudo` with the same results

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days i would get errors while installing Rails aswell, but nowadays we have [Installrails.com](http://installrails.com)

I have never encountered any errors while following the tutorials on that site. You might want to give that a try.